# Red Compound from Glycine and Glycerol?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, alcohols, reactivity, esters, amino-acids

I got an unexpected reaction which I'm trying to explain to myself:

I mixed 10 parts glycerol with 1 part glycine at ~90C and to my great surprise the mixture turned from transparent to a tint of red. I had maybe 1-2% water in there too. There might have been a very slight evolution of gas but that most probably was just the water boiling out.

I googled to try to find an answer to no avail. Does anyone know what could have happened?

Comment: No idea nor I want to start a search but this could be a starting point https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Maillard-reaction-of-sugars-with-glycine-in-system-Wijayanti/6f1dfa5424284c569abc94c5e8e723405cf2ed53?p2df

Comment: @Alchimista: I'll read into it. Thank you!!

Comment: Your temperature might be too low, but a little colour can go a long way and acrolein can form from glycerol, but usually catalysts are involved. An imine or enamine between glycine and an acrolein intermediate might not be impossible